# How to fix - The selected currency and country of Nigeria/NGN are incompatible

Tags: ads, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I am facing an issue where I am receiving the error message "The selected currency and country of Nigeria/NGN are incompatible" on my Google Ads platform. I would like to seek guidance on how to resolve this issue effectively. Can anyone provide insights or solutions to help me align the currency and country settings for Nigeria/NGN correctly? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

See attached screenshot.

[image]